# how to store BigInteger values in oracle database

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, oracle10g

I have connected Java program to Oracle database using JDBC. I want to store `BigInteger` values(512 bits) in the database. What should be the type of the column?

I m trying like this:

I have taken a column of number type in the database.

I converted `BigInteger` to `BigDecimal` like this:

```
BigInteger b=new BigInteger("5779857570957802579079");
Number n =b;
BigDecimal d=(BigDecimal)n;

PreparedStatement pstmt=con.prepareStatemant("insert into database values(?,?)");
pstmt.setString(1,"john");
pstmt.setBigDecimal(2,d);
```

I am getting the following exception:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to java.math.BigDecimal
root cause 

java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to java.math.BigDecimal
```

Is there anything wrong in this code snippet? If there is, please suggest other methods.

Comment: Please format your question with lists. Some pointers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: can i store BigDecimal in a column of NUMBER type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not answering directly your question, but i only see one oracle datatype that can store a 512 bits number : varchar2(156) (156 = abs(log(2^512))+2)

So i would rather convert the biginteger to a string rather than a bigdecimal.

Answer (score 3):

Both BigInteger and BigDecimal extend java.lang.Number, however this does not mean that you can cast from BigInteger up to Number then down to BigDecimal.

There is a constructor in BigDecimal that takes a BigInteger, so try:

```
BigDecimal d = new BigDecimal(b);
```

Comment: i tried but i m getting another exception.
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.sql.SQLException: [Oracle][ODBC]Invalid precision value.
root cause 

java.sql.SQLException: [Oracle][ODBC]Invalid precision value

Comment: Possible that the type of the column you are inserting into doesn't accept BigDecimal?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a decimal/numeric value depending on your db limits.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this way:

```
 oracle.sql.NUMBER numberValue = new oracle.sql.NUMBER(bigIntegerValue);
 cs.setObject(id, numberValue, OracleTypes.NUMBER);
```

where `bigIntegerValue` is an instance of `java.math.BigInteger`, it works for me

Comment: It would still not fit into a NUMBER column, as the NUMBER datatype is limited to about 40 digits max.